# what is the best security application to check if someone has copied my files with a usb and how to stop that

Tags: encryption

I need an encryption application that will detect who has accessed my files from my laptop via a usb and also to help me block memory sticks to access my files and laptop without my permission.

Comment: What encryption has to do with the detecting of copying the files via USB? Could you please elaborate more about it?

Comment: This is a proprietary solution: http://www.endpointprotector.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think encryption has to do any thing with it but there is one such [application on github](https://github.com/alaska/deadman) this will prevent USB sticks from accessing your laptop without your permission. Another application is [usbkill](https://github.com/hephaest0s/usbkill). Both of them will shutdown your computer whenever a USB device is plugged in or removed. usbkill doesn't work on windows, but supports device whitelisting.

**edit:** as far as seeing who has accessed your files is concerned, neither of them do that. But they do prevent access.